# Listen for swipe/touch events with Photoswipe gallery plugin

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

There is one particular photoswipe event that listen when the gallery has changed.

```
// After slides change
// (after content changed)
pswp.listen('afterChange', function() { });
```

I am wondering if there might be a way to detect from which direction the change apeared, so from left or right. Does anyone have an idea?

http://photoswipe.com/documentation/api.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may compare indexes in this event handler, `pswp.getCurrentIndex()` will return you current slide index.